# Haskell mongodb: Convert Binary value back to ByteString

Tags: mongodb, haskell

This is something simple and stupid that I cant just see.

If a new type is defined:

```
newtype Binary

Constructors
Binary ByteString

Instances:
Eq Binary    
Ord Binary   
Read Binary  
Show Binary  
Typeable Binary  
Val Binary
```

How can I deconstruct the Binary value to get the ByteString back?

If I want to save a binary data into mongodb, say a jpg picture, I am able to construct the Val Binary type out of ByteString read from the filesystem. I then insert it into a document.

When I read the data back from the database and take it out of the document I end up with the Binary type and I am sooo stuck with it. I can not get the ByteString type back for use with ByteString.writeFile.

So skipping all the connection stuff the flow is like this:

```
file <- B.readFile "pic.jpg" -- reading file
let doc = ["file" =: (Binary file)] -- constructing a document to be inserted
run $ insert_ "files" doc -- insert the document
r <- run $ fetch (select [] "files") -- get Either Failure Document back from db
let d = either (error . show) (id ) r -- Get the Document out
let f  = at "file" d :: Binary -- Get the data out of the document of type Binary
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `newtype` looks like this,

```
newtype Binary = Binary ByteString
```

then you can simply pattern match on the constructor to get the `ByteString` back:

```
unBinary :: Binary -> ByteString
unBinary (Binary s) = s
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you !!! I knew it was stupid )) So is it the normal way to de-construct a newtype like this by pattern match?

Comment: You could also newtype Binary = Binary { unBinary :: ByteString }, which will create the function for you.  That's the usual way I do it.

Comment: @mindreader Thank you. If I was creating the newtype myself I'd do the record but newtype Binary is defined in the library. I assumed that there should be a function to de-construct back similar to record syntax. But pattern match works just as well, it was stupid of me to miss this.